# Compile TensorFlow v1.8.0 cuda/include/cublas_v2.h: No such file or directory

Tags: tensorflow

When I compile TensorFlow v1.8

```
ERROR: /work/tensorflow/tensorflow/stream_executor/BUILD:52:1: C++ compilation of rule '//tensorflow/stream_executor:cuda_platform' failed (Exit 1)
tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:16:36: fatal error: cuda/include/cublas_v2.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 119.973s, Critical Path: 43.00s
INFO: 3322 processes, local.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

I find `/usr/local/cuda/include` don't have this file. How can get it?

Answer (score 0):

Running `bazel clean --expunge` and then compiling again seems to have fixed it for me.

Compiling tensorflow 1.12.3 with bazel 0.15.2

Comment: Also compiling with Cuda 10.1 on Ubuntu 18.04